# Accordion content panel

Tags: jquery

All, Forgive me I am a newbie for jquery ui, I have a question for the api accordion. 
After reading the [accordion api](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/). 
I found it doesn't tell me more about what is the content panel .After I test, I found `p` and `div` html element could be the content panel. But I am not sure which one is better. Anyway ,Any other element could be it ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use jquery or jquery ui selector to select your proper element. 
Example: `$( ".selector" )`. Of course any element could be your content panel and it is up to you to use which element. Most of the people use "div" for accordion , but it is not necessary  and you can use the element you like.